# Issue with EventEmitter inheritance

Tags: node.js, events

I'm having a small issue, playing around with module patterns. I'm trying to attach an eventemitter to my library, but it doesn't seem to work and I get :

```
cmd.on('message',function(msg){
    ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My lib looks like :

```
var util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

var TestLib = function() {
    var self = this;

    function sendRandom(cb){
        self.emit('message','whatever');
        cb(null,0);
    }

    return {
        init: function(cb) {
            console.log('init');
            cb(null);
        },

        run: function(params,cb){
            console.log('running ',params);
            sendRandom(function(err,res){
                 if(err){
                     cb(new Error(err));
                 }else{
                    cb(null,res);
                 }
            });
        },

        close: function(cb) {}
    };
};

util.inherits(TestLib, EventEmitter);
module.exports = TestLib;
```

And I call it as such :

```
var cmd = require(__dirname+'/bin/testlib.js')();
cmd.on('message',function(msg){
    log(msg);
});
cmd.init(function(err){
    if(err){
        log(err);
    }else{
        cmd.run(line,function(err,res){
            if(err){
                log(err);
            }else{
                log(res);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, but what?

Comment: Add `EventEmitter.call(this)` within the constructor of `TestLib`.

Comment: ````var TestLib = function() { EventEmitter.call(this);```` doesn't change anything

Comment: Oh, yeah, I've just seen that you are actually returning another object from within the constructor.

Comment: `cmd` is not an object for which you inherit from `EvenEmitter`, so it hasn't the `on` method. It is an object defined and returned within the constructor of `TestLib`, so you have not an actual instance of `TestSuite` and extending it won't help in any case.

Comment: Yeah I got that far too, how do I listen to events in this case? do I need to return the emit method within the return of ````Testlib````?

Comment: Why don't you attach `init`, `run` and the others to the prototype of your class? I need to understand what's your intended design.

Comment: as I said, I'm mostly playing around with module patterns, that one I took from KrakenJS, example here : https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-example-with-passport/blob/master/lib/user.js I'm just wondering how I'd add an eventlistener to such a module. Of course, I could make it into a regular constructor/prototype module, but where would be the fun in that? :-)

Answer (score 0):

see whether the example below helps you.

**testLib.js**

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

function TestLib(ms) {
  var self = this;
  EventEmitter.call(this);

  this.random = function() {
    //emitting 'random' event randomly
    var ms = Math.random() * 100000 % 3000;
    console.log('emitting random event in ' + ms + ' milliseconds');
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.emit('random', ms);
      self.random();
    }, ms);
    return self;
  }
}

util.inherits(TestLib, EventEmitter);
module.exports = TestLib;
```

**test.js**

```
var TestLib = require('./testLib');

new TestLib()
  .random()
  .on('random', function(ms) {
    console.log('random event emitted after ' + ms + ' milliseconds');
  });
```

to run it, execute `node test.js`

Comment: unfortunately no, my question isn't about how to inherit an event emitter, I know how to do that already, but it is about how to add an event emitter to this particular pattern! Thanks anyway!